# Django - Adding a primary key to an existing model with data

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key

This is the existing model in a djnago app:

```
class Task_Master_Data(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project_Master_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

I want to add a new field (which will be a primary key):

```
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
```

When I am making migrations from the terminal, it will provide me with the option of adding a default value, but it will, understandably, bring an error of:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: new__main_task_master_data.task_id
```

What would be the best way forward for this kind of a scenario without having to delete all the data.

Note, I am using the default sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of an old bug that is still unfixed. [See here for the ticket.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27339)

I have created a workaround.

First create an empty migration (change `taskapp` to the name of the app where your `models.py` with `Task_Master_Data` lives):

```
python manage.py makemigrations taskapp --empty
```

Then copy the below migrations into this file and run `python manage.py migrate` but be sure to adjust the name of the app (replace `taskapp` with the name of your app) and the dependencies (`0010_task_master_data` should be replaced by the name of the migration that comes before it).

First the existing rows in the database need values for the new `task_id` field. I solved this by creating an `IntegerField` with `null=True`, which I then manually fill using a `RunPython` command. I then remove the `id` field (my previous primary key), and use `AlterField` to change the field into the `AutoField`. A default value is required, but it should never be used. When you create a new `Task_Master_Data` the `task_id` should be auto-incrementing.

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.4 on 2022-05-11 07:13

from django.db import migrations, models


def fill_taskid(apps, schema_editor):
    # be sure to change it to your app here
    Task_Master_Data = apps.get_model("taskapp", "Task_Master_Data")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    tasks = Task_Master_Data.objects.using(db_alias).all()
    for i, task in enumerate(tasks):
        task.task_id = i
    Task_Master_Data.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_update(tasks, ["task_id"])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('taskapp', '0010_task_master_data'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='task_master_data',
            name='task_id',
            field=models.IntegerField(null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(fill_taskid),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='task_master_data',
            name='id',
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='task_master_data',
            name='task_id',
            field=models.AutoField(default=-1, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Note that depending on the state of your database you might need to rollback some of your migrations. The migration I created should work if your database is in a state where your `task_id` field does not exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and good to know there is a way out instead of just deleting the data, which I would have done since my data was test only and minimal, but decided to ask the question anyway.  Have not got the time to try this out (will probably do it on the weekend and give you feedback) but didn't want to your efforts to be seen ignored so decided to drop this comment in :)